# Most efficient multi-find/replace solution in Excel VBA

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I'm looking to improve the runtime and efficiency of my VBA code that performs multiple `Replace` operations on an Excel Spreadsheet. I started out with the following (please forgive me for this horrendous mess):

<sub>**Note:** Some values/symbols did not show up correctly in this first piece of code
(blank values displayed in 'What:=""' and the ">" and "<" symbols displayed as normal ">" and "<" symbols, which they are not)</sub>

```
Private Sub symbolCheck()
Range("A2").Select
'Selects only to the end of all the data in the file to reduce processing time
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

'Proceed with removing invalid symbols
'Apostrophe/Closing Single Quote
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="'", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Apostrophe
Selection.Replace What:="`", Replacement:="'", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Opening Single Quote
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="'", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Double Open Quotes
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Double Closing Quotes
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Dash
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Registered Trademark (R)
Selection.Replace What:="®", Replacement:="(R)", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Trademark (TM)
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="(TM)", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Degree Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="°", Replacement:=" degrees", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Multiplication/x Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="×", Replacement:="x", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Upside-Down Question Mark Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="¿", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Solid Bullet Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Triple Dots Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="...", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Euro Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Linebreak Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="|", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Less Than Symbol
Selection.Replace What:="<", Replacement:="<", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Greater Than Symbol
Selection.Replace What:=">", Replacement:=">", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Half Fraction
Selection.Replace What:="½", Replacement:=" 1/2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'Three Quarter Fraction
Selection.Replace What:="¾", Replacement:=" 3/4", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
'One Quarter Fraction
Selection.Replace What:="¼", Replacement:=" 1/4", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

This code takes around **31.57 seconds** to run on about 15000 row (~150 column) file.

After doing a decent amount of research and trial and error:

- I'm using the little tweaks (disabling various Excel activity) suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018880/2962937).
- I've adjusted/cleaned up my code according to the example given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/25016/97532), removing my extra `Replace` criteria that was not needed and using the `With` statement so I don't have to keep repetively referencing the range. However, I did not use the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` suggestion given in this example because my code actually ran much slower than when I use `UsedRange`.

Leaving me with this updated version of my code:

```
Private Sub symbolCheck()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim r1 As Range
'Range("A2").Select
'Selects only to the end of all the data in the file to reduce processing time
'Set r1 = Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
Set r1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'Proceed with removing invalid symbols
With r1
'Apostrophe/Closing Single Quote
.Replace What:="’", Replacement:=Chr(39), LookAt:=xlPart
'Apostrophe
.Replace What:="`", Replacement:=Chr(39), LookAt:=xlPart
'Opening Single Quote
.Replace What:="‘", Replacement:=Chr(39), LookAt:=xlPart
'Double Open Quotes
.Replace What:="“", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart
'Double Closing Quotes
.Replace What:="”", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart
'Dash
.Replace What:="–", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart
'Registered Trademark (R)
.Replace What:="®", Replacement:="(R)", LookAt:=xlPart
'Trademark (TM)
.Replace What:="™", Replacement:="(TM)", LookAt:=xlPart
'Degree Symbol
.Replace What:="°", Replacement:=" degrees", LookAt:=xlPart
'Multiplication/x Symbol
.Replace What:="×", Replacement:="x", LookAt:=xlPart
'Upside-Down Question Mark Symbol
.Replace What:="¿", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
'Solid Bullet Symbol
.Replace What:="•", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
'Triple Dots Symbol
.Replace What:="…", Replacement:="...", LookAt:=xlPart
'Euro Symbol
.Replace What:="€", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
'Linebreak Symbol
.Replace What:="|", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart
'Less Than Symbol
.Replace What:="<", Replacement:="<", LookAt:=xlPart
'Greater Than Symbol
.Replace What:=">", Replacement:=">", LookAt:=xlPart
'Half Fraction
.Replace What:="½", Replacement:=" 1/2", LookAt:=xlPart
'Three Quarter Fraction
.Replace What:="¾", Replacement:=" 3/4", LookAt:=xlPart
'One Quarter Fraction
.Replace What:="¼", Replacement:=" 1/4", LookAt:=xlPart
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

After making those adjustments I'm still left around **26.5-27.8 seconds** for the code to run on the same 15000 row (~150 column) file.

I've also come upon, but have not tried:

- I'm curious whether using a variation of Option 2 (using regEx) given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263284/2962937) would help improve my time anymore.
- And I'm not sure whether going about this multiple find/replace action using arrays like [here](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/14/find-and-replace-all) would be beneficial or help speed up the code anymore

Does anyone have any ideas or critique on how I can further increase the speed of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *finally* found a method that greatly reduces the time it takes for my piece of code to run. Building off of a method I stumbled upon [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/702948-search-replace-defined-array-visual-basic-applications.html) I reduced the runtime of this `Sub Routine` all the way down to **5-7 seconds for 15000 rows (140 columns)**.

First, I dumped the `UsedRange` into a `Variable Array` (since cycling through an `Array` is a lot quicker than looping through actual cells), then I test each slot to first make sure it's not empty (this saved me loads of time), then if it wasn't empty I tested each slot for each value I was looking to replace by using the `Instr()` function. This way I can save time by only performing each `Substitute` only if the value was found in that slot.

```
Sub NewAndImprovedSymbolCheck()
Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
starttime = Timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    For j = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)
        If MyArray(i, j) <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", Chr(39))
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:=Chr(39), LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "`") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "`", Chr(39))
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="`", Replacement:=Chr(39), LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", Chr(39))
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:=Chr(39), LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", """")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", """")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", "-")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "®") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "®", "(R)")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="®", Replacement:="(R)", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", "(TM)")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:="(TM)", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "°") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "°", " degrees")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="°", Replacement:=" degrees", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "×") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "×", "x")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="×", Replacement:="x", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¿") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¿", "")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="¿", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", "")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", "...")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:="...", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "", "")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "|") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "|", ",")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="|", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "<") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "<", "<")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="<", Replacement:="<", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), ">") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), ">", ">")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:=">", Replacement:=">", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "½") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "½", " 1/2")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="½", Replacement:=" 1/2", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¾") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¾", " 3/4")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="¾", Replacement:=" 3/4", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
            If InStr(1, MyArray(i, j), "¼") > 0 Then
                MyArray(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(i, j), "¼", " 1/4")
                'MyArray(i, j).Replace What:="¼", Replacement:=" 1/4", LookAt:=xlPart
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
ActiveSheet.UsedRange = MyArray

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox Timer - starttime
End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed, the single slowest thing to do is accessing cells; good approach, but it still reads as macro-recorder code, I'd strongly recommend taking whatever performance hit comes with greater readability and maintainability.

Comment: I understand that it reads as macro-recorder, but my mission was to simply decrease the processing time of the code (as I stated in my question). Readability is not an issue for me because it'll be me alone maintaining this code, so as long as I can understand it (which I do), then I consider that mission (increasing speed) accomplished.

Comment: Not my downvote (I actually upvoted this answer), however I'm not buying the "I'm the only maintainer" argument. Code should be written as if *the next person to maintain it* is a dangerous axe murderer that knows where you live =)

Comment: If you're after speed improvements, don't use Worksheet functions on in memory arrays, VBA has it's own replace function - use that. Additionally, you could combine the dictionary approach of @Mat'sMug with your code above for much better maintainability

Comment: There's a reason I didn't use the replace function. It has a character limitation and many of the values I check exceed that limit.

Comment: @CaffeinatedMike, I know this is a very old comment, but VBAs `Replace` function does not have a limitation in terms of number of characters in any of the three string arguments (`Expression`, `Find`, `Replace`). What limitation are you talking about here?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about the performance (looks like pretty intensive work anyway), but code-wise, it can definitely improve!

You're repeating the `.Replace` call as many times as you have things to replace. *Extract it into its own method*, and *separate the concerns* of "knowing what to look for" and "replacing stuff".

Start with renaming `r1` to a meaningful name, adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and referencing the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. Then do this:

```
Dim searchRange As Range
Set searchRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Dim replacements As Dictionary
Set replacements = New Dictionary
With replacements
    .Add "’", "'"
    .Add "`", "'"
    .Add "‘", "'"
    .Add "“", """"
    .Add "”", """"
    .Add "–", "-"
    .Add "®", "(R)"
    .Add "™", "(TM)"
    .Add "°", " degrees"
    .Add "×", "x"
    .Add "¿", vbNullString
    .Add "•", vbNullString
    .Add "…", "..."
    .Add "€", vbNullString
    .Add "|", ","
    .Add "<", "<"
    .Add ">", ">"
    .Add "½", " 1/2"
    .Add "¾", " 3/4"
    .Add "¼", " 1/4"
End With
```

When you have a new symbol to replace, you just `.Add` it and its replacement to that `Dictionary`, and now you have a single data structure to iterate, contrary to the "dual array" suggestion you've come across - whenever you have two arrays with indices lined up and a requirement for them to "keep in sync", you're using the wrong data structure.

The benefit here isn't one of performance, it's one of maintainability and readability: instead of reading like a macro-recorder script, your code starts reading more naturally, like actual code meant to be *read* and *maintained*, not just *executed*.

```
Dim key As String
Dim value As String
For Each key In replacements.Keys
    value = replacements(key)
    If Asc(key) <> Asc(value) Then
        searchRange.Replace What:=key, Replacement:=value, LookAt:=xlPart
    Else
        Debug.Print "Extraneous key '" & key & "' could be removed from dictionary."
    End If
Next
```

Notice I'm checking if the `key` matches the `value`, because I noticed you have a number of superfluous replacements there, doing work for nothing.

So you are scanning something like 2,250,000 cells *20 times*; it completing in 26-28 seconds means just a little more than 1 second per iteration is spent searching/replacing across 2.25 *million* cells: I wouldn't call that *inefficient*, but skipping no-op iterations that replace a value by the same value (looking at "<" and ">" in particular), and avoiding calls to `Chr()`, could possibly trim another 1-3 seconds from it.

Also, I wouldn't rely on `UsedRange`, as it tends to not always match the range that you're interested in: if that's the case, you could skip a few thousand iterations and shave off another couple of seconds by working with the *actually used* range. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423252/1188513).

Comment: Great piece of advice @Mat's Mug, thank you. Using a `dictionary` for this does appear to be much more readable and maintainable. Though, I should've mentioned that those two values you mentioned ("<" and ">") were originally in some other format, but changed when I pasted them here for some reason. As for using `Chr()` I had no choice due to my file simply wiping out those values instead of replacing them with the unicode apostrophe. I will certainly consider this approach, but I am still holding out some hope that someone out there has an idea that will help speed things up a bit somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested out both the `regex` and array looping methods that I provided in links above and they indeed did not improve the speed of the code (`regex` was actually much slower).

I've even looked into crazy ideas like dumping the entire spreadsheet into as few cells as possible just while performing the replaces (and along the way I found out some interesting limitations of a single cell that I hadn't previously known)

I've also tested out @Mat's Mug's suggestion of using a `scripting dictionary` and though, yes, it is tidier it also was slightly slower than my second piece of code above. So, if ANYONE has any other ideas to try I'm all ears.